# What's the payment model Google uses for Android In-App Subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-subscription

I want to sell monthly subscription for my android app, which means a fixed amount would be debited from the user's account each month.

My question is, how much do I need to pay Google as transaction fee and how often? I know that Google charges 30% transaction fee, but is it just one time fee or it would be charged each month for a subscription?

Does Google also reduce the transaction fee after an year or so like Apple does(30% for the first year then 15% for subsequent years)?

I couldn't find much detail [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en), other than the transaction fee. Please guide if there are other available documents on the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't downvote this question. This is a valid question, considering Google's confusing and obscure documentation on the subject. There's strong and real speculation for over a year now of a possible 30% for the first month/year/charge, and 15% after that, but nothing concrete from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You have to pay 30% of comission each time a transaction is charged(In your case each month).

**2)** Google doesnt reduce the fee after a certain time has passed

**EDIT**

Confirmation of point one:
[image]

LINK: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html